# installing RDFlib on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, nose, rdflib

I am trying to install RDFlib on ubuntu 12.04 but am unable to do so.
I have downloaded a zip file and am running 
python setup.py install 
but am getting error 
 Requires Nose. Try:

```
    $ sudo easy_install nose

Exiting.
```

But when i try to install nose it is not getting installed
Can you tell me what to do as i know nothing about nose

I have also tried 
 easy_install rdflib but it is also not working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend installing RDFLib with [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).  Follow these [instructions](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/linux/#setuptools-pip) for getting pip up and running.

Once pip is installed.  Installing RDFLib should be as easy as:

```
$ pip install rdflib
```